# sticker pull off effect with css

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to create a sticker pull off effect with css.

For that I found this example: https://codepen.io/patrickkunka/pen/axEgL

Now I have three problems.

1. I'm using an image and not only colors.
2. The peeling effect is way to far in the example
3. Because I'm using an image, I can't move it around.

Now let me show the problems with some code:

```css
.test-sticker {
  /*
  .sticker:hover .sticky{
 transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  */
}
.test-sticker .anim750 {
  transition: all 750ms ease-in-out;
}
.test-sticker .sticker {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.test-sticker .sticker .sticky {
  transform: rotate(-125deg);
}
.test-sticker .sticker .sticky {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
}
.test-sticker .sticker .reveal .circle {
  font-family: 'helvetica neue', arial;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.test-sticker .sticker .reveal .circle {
  background: purple;
}
.test-sticker .sticker .circle_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.test-sticker .sticker .circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 999px;
}
.test-sticker .sticker .back {
  height: 10px;
  top: 30px;
}
.test-sticker .sticker .back .circle {
  margin-top: -130px;
  background-color: green;
}
.test-sticker .sticker .front {
  height: 150px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -140px 20px -140px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.test-sticker .sticker .front .circle {
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/Wordpress_Blue_logo.png");
  background-size: 140px 140px;
  transform: rotate(-235deg);
}
.test-sticker .sticker:hover .back {
  height: 90px;
  top: 110px;
}
.test-sticker .sticker:hover .back .circle {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-sticker">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sticker">
      <div class="reveal circle_wrapper">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="sticky">
        <div class="front circle_wrapper">
          <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="sticky anim750">
        <div class="back circle_wrapper anim750">
          <div class="circle anim750"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the greed circle just about 50% and not like now 80%?

Is there a fancy way to get the purple circle extended the same way like the green one? so when I hover over the image, I want to see the back of the sticker, which is white at the end.

Comment: Like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YjvwbW

Comment: no you miss understand me, this is how my design looks like and what I want to do with css: https://image.ibb.co/kDXqfe/Unbenannt_3.png